# Regarding identical copies of gedit files

Tags: filesystems, directory, ls, filenames, gedit

When ever I save a **gedit** file in a directory, two copies of it get saved with identical content. Ex: If the gedit file is named as `file_name` and saved in **Home** directory then when u `ls` the Home directory you get `file_name` and `file_name~` in the list. When the `file` command is run against them I get `ASCII text, with very long lines` for both of them when I view their contents using the `less` command they seem to largely contain identical content. The ~ file is a copy of the file when it was saved for the penultimate time. Can someone please help me in understanding as to why such a file (the file with a trailing ~ mark in its name ) is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are backup files that gedit creates by default.  You can disable this feature by going to

`Preferences → Editor`

and unchecking the line

`Create a backup copy of files before saving`

Comment: but even after saving a what is the purpose of creating its backup in the same folder?

Comment: The file with the ~ at the end is the backup.  It is the previous version of the file that you just saved.  You can try this out by making a file called test.txt.  Put the line "this is a test" and save it.  Then open the file in gedit and add another line "This is another test" and save it.  Then look at the file with the tilda. It will just have the original line.

Comment: ok u mean to say that this ~ version is the last saved copy...Thanx cleared my doubts although i still dont get the purpose of this procedure....say u have a saved version of a file...it means it has been written into the disc....then what is the purpose of saving the last saved version?......to add to that what is the purpose of saving it in the same directory? I can speculate about some weird situations like say what if accidentally i selec all press del and save it,then may be it is useful,but these chances are so rare aren't they? So is this feature worth it?Thanx for the detailed example

Comment: I have edited the question accordingly

Comment: Yeah. I've never found the feature too useful and don't like the extra files messing up my directories. I usually turn it off. I guess it is just personal preference at that point.